# How to get all aggregations by avoiding 1 filter from the elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an elasticsearch query which gets aggregations from the query results. The aggregations work fine because if i select to get all dresses from "women fashion" category that are golden in color.

The aggregations are working fine as it only returns the color golden. But logically we need all the colors in that aggregation.

On the frontend filter we are directly showing records from the aggregations requests. Right now On the frontend when someone selects "golden" color, it drills down and removes all other color filters and only shows golden color.

We need to somehow avoid the color from the aggregations to show all the results.

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "category": "women_fashion"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "variations",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [{
                                        "match": {
                                            "variations.color": "golden"
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    "should": null
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "brands": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 10,
                "field": "brand"
            }
        },
        "min_price": {
            "min": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        },
        "max_price": {
            "max": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        },
        "variations": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "variations"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "size": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size": 100,
                        "field": "variations.size"
                    }
                },
                "color": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size": 100,
                        "field": "variations.color"
                    }
                },
                "waist_size": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size": 100,
                        "field": "variations.waist_size"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Mapping:**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "products": {
            "properties": {
                "variations": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample document:**

```
{
    "title": "100% Cotton Unstitched Suit For Men",
    "slug": "100-cotton-unstitched-suit-for-men",
    "price": 200,
    "sale_price": 0,
    "vendor_id": 32,
    "featured": 0,
    "viewed": 20,
    "stock": 4,
    "sku": "XXX-B",
    "rating": 0,
    "active": 1,
    "vendor_name": "vendor_name",
    "category": [
        "men_fashion",
        "traditional_clothing",
        "unstitched_fabric"
    ],
    "image": "imagename.jpg",
    "variations": [
        {
            "variation_id": "34",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-C",
            "size": "m",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "35",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-D",
            "size": "l",
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

After going through lots of documentation, there is something called a **post-filter** that can somehow solve this issue. I tried using it but its a bit complicated. Does anyone have any past experience with this.

---

**MY Updated Query with global aggrgations:**
I have tried using global aggregations, but it now shows all the brands in elasticsearch, where as i want to show brands associated with products in that category.

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "category": "women_fashion"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "variations",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [{
                                        "match": {
                                            "variations.color": "golden"
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    "should": null
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "all_brands" : {
            "global" : {},
            "aggs" : { 
                "brands": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size": 10,
                        "field": "brand"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "brands": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 10,
                "field": "brand"
            }
        },
        "min_price": {
            "min": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        },
        "max_price": {
            "max": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        },
        "variations": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "variations"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "size": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size": 100,
                        "field": "variations.size"
                    }
                },
                "color": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size": 100,
                        "field": "variations.color"
                    }
                },
                "waist_size": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size": 100,
                        "field": "variations.waist_size"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html#_global_bucket:

Use `"global" : {}` in aggregation seem do the job.

If you need filter aggregation after that, use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html.

Comment: thanks @thomas for your answer, but when i use global aggregations they just get me all the results. I have updated my code with the query that i am using

Comment: Then, you can filter the aggregation with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html.