# Elasticsearch aggregation not being applied to filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Here is my query. I am trying to get all products that are inside "men_fashion" and "men_shoes" category (categories are being used as terms/tags). Then i want to query the whole result set and search for products that have "men boots yellow" in them.

The below query works perfectly fine, but now i am not getting the correct aggregation results. It gives me all the brands where as i am only interested in the brands.

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "men boots yellow"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "active": 1
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "category": "men_fashion"
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "category": "men_shoes"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "brands": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 100,
                "field": "brand"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this might be due to the filter i have applied, but if this is somehow complicated i am ok with using a simple query that would achieve this without the filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a [post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) instead of a normal query filter, try like this instead:

```
{
  "size": 15,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "men boots yellow"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "active": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "category": "men_fashion"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "category": "men_shoes"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "brands": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 100,
        "field": "brand"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think u missed the query parameter. But thats perfect. Thanks Val. I do have another question related to elasticsearch which has been bugging me for the past month. u can find out my question here
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463938/how-to-get-all-aggregations-by-avoiding-1-filter-from-the-elasticsearch-query. 

Basically its about multi selecting aggregations. when i click on any filter eg color: golden. It removes all other aggregations and just shows me that golden color. But sites like amazon have multiple colors to select. Is there anything simple than filtered aggregation

Comment: After some testing i realized that there is something wrong with the query. I am not able to search most of the phrases. How can i modify this so anything thats a bit relevant should be shown

Comment: I suggest you create another question since this one is solved.